# How can I parse a Vec<String> of individual lines as XML in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a Rust command line program to grep log files.  It reads the input files line by line, and creates records containing the "base" log line (with timestamp, logging level, thread name, class name etc) and "extra" log lines (containing embedded XML or JSON messages).  Here's a simplified example:

```
(preceding line)
[2020-10-02 12:00:00,000Z][INFO][input-io][XMLReader] Received XML message:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Outer foo="bar"><Inner baz="qux"/></Outer>
(following line)
```

I've got to the point where I'm trying to pretty-print an embedded XML message for a single record.  What I need to do is take the "extra" log lines (stored in a `Vec<String>`) and pass them to one of the XML pull reader libraries (I'm currently looking at [quick_xml](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.19.0/quick_xml/) because it behaves well in benchmarks, but I'd use a different one if necessary).

My problem here is that the quick_xml `Reader` class expects a `BufRead` implementation, but I don't know how to create that from a `Vec<String>`.  Can anyone offer any advice?

Alternatively, some XML pull reader libraries in other languages support feeding text in arbitrary chunks.  Is there an XML library which does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Vec::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.join) to merge all lines into one:

```rust
use quick_xml::Reader;
use quick_xml::events::Event;

fn main() {
    let vec_of_string = vec![
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>".to_owned(),
        "<Outer foo=\"bar\">".to_owned(),
        "<Inner baz=\"qux\"/>".to_owned(),
        "</Outer>".to_owned(),
    ];
 
    // HERE WE GO   
    let xml = vec_of_string.join("\n");
    
    // copy-paste from quick_xml's documentation
    let mut reader = Reader::from_str(&xml);
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    loop {
        match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {
            Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
                println!(
                    "name:{:?} attributes values:{:?}", 
                    e.name(),
                    e.attributes()
                        .map(|a| a.unwrap().value)
                        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                );
            },
            Ok(Event::Eof) => break,
            Err(e) => panic!("Error at position {}: {:?}", reader.buffer_position(), e),
            _ => (),
        }

        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the result of that `join()` call is *owned* data, and therefore copied, given that I can have a reference to it in a wider scope than the original vector.  I was hoping to be able to feed the source data into a pull parser one line at a time (without having to copy it) but if this is my option I'll take it; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement [BufRead trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) for you Vec of Strings.
However, you need to overcome [Orphan Rule](https://blog.mgattozzi.dev/orphan-rules/) because you do not own both Vec type and BufRead trait.

So you need to use wrapper type:

```rust
struct BufReadVecWrapper{
   // You can use reference to slice of strings 
   // if you want to preserve your vec
   strings: Vec<String>, 
}

impl BufRead for BufReadVecWrapper{
   // Implement all methods here
   // basically, you just send bytes of your strings here
}

let wrapper = BufReadVecWrapper{strings: your_vec};
let mut reader = quick_xml::Reader::from_reader(wrapper);
```

You can now use reader as in [MaxV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64176392/8195987) and avoid extra allocation on joining all your strings into one. However, it would require much more effort.

Comment: Thanks, worth a try. However, given that I have a very limited use case, and do not need a fully featured XML parser, I have decided to give in to hubris and write my own (I also need a JSON parser with similar requirements). Given that it will define a feed() function, taking a string reference and an impl of a callback trait, it should require zero allocations.